# How can I detect if Activity is already installed in device, and prepare resources after activity installation is detected?

Tags: java, android

There are two applications `AppMine` and `AppExtern`. I am developing `AppMine`. It's known that there is an Activity class named `com.xxx.XActivity` in `AppExtern`, so I want to start this activity from `com.mine.MyActivity` in my `AppMine`.

`AppExtern` can be downloaded from Google Play. Since `AppExtern` is an external App, It isn't sure if it's installed in my Android device when `startActivity()` is called in in `com.mine.MyActivity`. I would like to start a Google Play app for `AppExtern` if it's not yet installed.

Also, I would like to give `AppExtern` a location parameter (current latitude and longitude) when starting the activity.

- If `AppExtern` is installed and GPS is enabled ... start activity `com.xxx.XActivity` with GPS params.
- If `AppExtern` is installed and GPS is disabled ... show a Toast and `finish()`.
- If `AppExtern` is not installed and GPS is enabled ... start Google Play app.
- If `AppExtern` is not installed and GPS is disabled ... start Google Play app.

How can this be done?

The only method I know to check if external app is installed, is to call `startActivity` inside `try{}`, and see if `ActivityNotFoundException` is thrown.

```java
try{
  final Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setClassName("xclient","com.xxx.XActivity");
  // Try to start activity in order to check if com.xxx.XActivity exists.
  startActivity(intent);

  // Finish the started activity?

  final Location location = ****; // Get GPS location using LocationManager.
  if(location == null){ // location is null if GPS is disabled for device.
    callbackHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
          "Cannot use GPS. Check your device settings.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
        }
    });
  }

  // Set latitude/longitude and start activity again.
  intent.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
  intent.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude());
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
  callbackHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      final String packageName = "xclient";
      final Intent intent = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ packageName));
      MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
      MyActivity.this.finish();
    }
  });
}
```

This DOESN'T work properly. The problem is that there are no chance to get latitude/longitude information AFTER app existance is checked. If external app exists but GPS is turned off, I should show a Toast and `finish()` to let the user know it's disabled, but the external app is already started. It seems that there are no way to `finish()` the started `com.xxx.XActivity` from `com.mine.MyActivity`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

```
List<PackageInfo> installedPackages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo installedPackage : installedPackages) {
    String packName = installedPackage.applicationInfo.packageName;

    if ("put AppExtern's packageName here".equals(packName )) {     
        //AppExtern is installed
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("xclient", "com.xxx.XActivity");

        final Location location = ****; // Get GPS location using LocationManager.
        if(location == null){           // location is null if GPS is disabled for device.
            callbackHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                      "Cannot use GPS. Check your device settings.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // finish();  you don't need to finish,because AppExtern is not started yet.
                    return;
                    }
                });
        }

        intent.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
        intent.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}

//AppExtern is not installed
//start Google Play app
```